# Does a third level domain wildcard certificate prove a fourth level domain website?

Tags: tls, certificates, websites

Suppose I have a certificate for `*.example.com` and privileged access to all `example.com` websites. Sure I could install the wildcard certificate into `https://api.example.com` website so that it can prove its identity. What about `https://www.cool.example.com`?

I'm facing this exact scenario with a fourth level domain name website. IE and Firefox refuse to connect to `https://www.cool.example.com` which serves `*.example.com` certificate to prove its identity (however when I request `https://cool.example.com` serving the same certificate the two browsers are both happy to connect).

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard certificates only cover one level of subdomains. You can however use subject alternative names to have more leeway.

You can see examples on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)